# How can i connect 9 7segments to a 3x4 keypad using only diodes making each 7segment displays only one number?

Tags: diodes, 7segmentdisplay, keypad

I want to make each button in the keypad to display one number using only diodes without using any decoders or ic.
thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have 3-phase power available?

Comment: And I want be rich without working... Come on, there are tasks and tools for these tasks. They should meet each other.

Comment: I don't know i'm using a 9 volt dc source from the circuit wizard simulation program. Spehro Pefhany

Comment: What **exact** reason is there for the "no decoders or ic" limitation?

Comment: Some kind of a test for the deep understanding for connections and current directions . Till now i spent a week trying to solve and i totaly failed !

Comment: Do you know what 'overconstrained' means? It's possible to do this without ICs but I think it would be a waste of time. Break the connections between the switches and it's easy.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I am curious about the 3-phase PS

Comment: Pleeease i'm some kind of a begginer can you explain it more for me ?

Comment: @EugeneSh. It should be possible with zener diodes, diodes and resistors to generate 3 non-overlapping pulses which could be fed to the switches and to 3 transistors bases through resistors. Then all you'd need would be diodes and resistors. Kind of what you'd do with chips anyway.

Comment: @minamagdy So as a beginner, you are dealing with junk and wasting your time which could be spent learning something more useful. Get appropriate parts for your project and build it. Don't try to invent the wheel having only square-shaped parts in hand.

Comment: I would like to if i could man but as i told before it a test and i have to solve it

Comment: @SpehroPefhany That was an impressive suggestion. Thank you for making this an interesting read.

Comment: I actually think this is an interesting question. While the constraints may not be practical, there is intellectual merit to problem solving.

Comment: How may voltage rails may we use?

Comment: As many as you want :)

Comment: Thats a huge help.

Comment: Homework questions with no attempt at a solution are closed.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got it!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6IYMb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### Explanation

Each LED labeled represents a parallel connection of each segment appropriate for that number as well as a current limiting resister for each.

When 1 is pressed, only 1 is forward biased.

When 2 is pressed, only 2 is forward biased.

When 3 is pressed, 2 and 3 are forward biased however 2 will not illuminate because the lion's share of the current is flowing through the zener which has 10V across it now.

When nothing is pressed, it is assumed that the forward drop of 1 and 2 are less than 5 so they are not on (the voltage can change if needed).

Comment: Not sure if this site is just for engineering situations or also for brain teasers. This is certainly the latter but I enjoyed it quite a bit.

Comment: Thank yoooou very much for your help i will try it and keep you updated. @Houston_Fortney. I think that is for both :) there is no big difference actully

Comment: It won't work - the -5V one fails but you are very close. Try adding a transistor rather than the zener.

Comment: Why does it fail?

Comment: 2 stays on when 3 is pushed

Comment: Thank you @SpehroPefhany. I had intended to place the resistors a bit differently, you are indeed correct.